# rails route using email instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Currently in my rails app am using `http://admin.evercam.io/users` to enlist all users, and using devise for showing a user further

```
 devise_for :users, devise_options

 resources :users, only: [:show, :index, :update] do
   get :impersonate, on: :member
 end
```

which giving me a single user on `http://admin.evercam.io/users/49`
but now what i want to do is just have a user on his/her email, as

```
http://admin.evercam.io/users?q=junaid@evercam.io
```

NOTE: am using Devise, do i need to create a new route or can be done within devise?

Answer (score 1):

In your user model:

```
def to_param
 email
end
```

The `to_param` method on ActiveRecord objects uses, by default, just the ID of the object. By putting this code in your model, you're overwriting the ActiveRecord default.

You can also use `friendly_id gem`.

Comment: by doing this `/users?q=junaid@evercam.io` this will possible?

Comment: query parameters in url is not good way in Rails. (we are not php developers) - explore friendly_id gem

Comment: yes we are not but when we are in need of something then its not php or rails. help if you can help :)